# How to redirect to li on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

How can I show li on click of a button? I want on click of assignment button,
Assign Lab Room & Technican li should open.

Below is my html code for it.

```
<div class="box-header" id = "liid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-left" style="cursor: move;">
        <li ><a href="#payment" data-toggle="tab">Application</a></li>
        <li class="active"  id="assigned"><a href="#appointment" data-toggle="tab">Assign Lab Room & Technican</a></li>                                 
        <li class=""><a href="#analysis" data-toggle="tab">Technican Analysis</a></li>
        <ng-container *ngIf="usertypeid==='3'">
        <li class=""><a href="#audit" data-toggle="tab">Audit1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#audit1" data-toggle="tab">Audit2</a></li>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</div>  

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" (click)="show()" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Assignment</button>
```

Below is my jQuery function as well:

```
show(){
    console.log("afdghj");
    $( "#assigned").show();            
}
```

Comment: @Tim `(click)="show()"` is fine, this is Angular, also `show(){...}` is almost certainly defined in an exported class and so `function` shouldn't be present, this way it is available in the view.

Comment: @NickA please write some script that will explain me about `show()` was defined  before and he is reassigning it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to simulate the click on your `<li>` when clicking on your button. This is not the appropiate answer if you want to redirect to your `#appointment` path, because the `href="#appointment"` is set in your `<a>` tag and not in your `<li>`.

Saying that, what I think you should do is to make your button really do what you want, and redirect to the path you want in its action.

Then, your code must be

```js
function show(){
    console.log("afdghj");
    window.location.href= '#appointment';
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-header" id = "liid">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-left" style="cursor: move;">
        <li ><a href="#payment" data-toggle="tab">Application</a></li>
        <li class="active" id="assigned"><a href="#appointment" data-toggle="tab">Assign Lab Room & Technican</a></li>                                 
        <li class=""><a href="#analysis" data-toggle="tab">Technican Analysis</a></li>
        <ng-container *ngIf="usertypeid==='3'">
        <li class=""><a href="#audit" data-toggle="tab">Audit1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#audit1" data-toggle="tab">Audit2</a></li>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</div>  

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" onclick="show()" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Assignment</button>
```

In jQuery `show()` event means to remove style `display: none` and `hide()`  does the opposite.